# Сайт не корректно отображается на смартфоне

Tags: html, jquery, css, responsive

Вот верстка
https://postolenko.github.io/vpodarok/index.html

Сайт резиновый и не адаптивный. Но на смартфоне отображается с обрывистым фоном. Как это исправить ?

Comment: Приведите [mcve] с демонстрацией проблемы без ссылок на сторонние сайты

Comment: Как сверстал так и отображается...

Comment: Поставил минус: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/213987) - приведите минимальный самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Сайт не резиновый и не адаптивный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решился вопрос тем что обертке сайта нужно было задать минимальную его ширину в пикселях.

```
.wrapper {
    min-width: 1140px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Задай ширину этих блоков пo vw:

```
width: 100vw;
```